# How to show the chart image in full width to screen?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The chart is generating so small.I am using asp.net chart control.How to show the chart image size without shrinking and stretching.How to make chart height and width  dynamic according to data in asp.net??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are using it exactly, but `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` has a `Width` and a `Height` property:

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Chart1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
Chart1.Width = 412;
Chart1.Height = 296;
Chart1.RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag;
//....
// Render chart control
Chart1.Page = this;
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(Page.Response.Output);
Chart1.RenderControl(writer);
```

or

```
<asp:chart id="Chart1" runat="server" Height="296px" Width="412px" ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" Palette="BrightPastel" imagetype="Png" BorderDashStyle="Solid" ...
```

For more details, I suggest checking the samples at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61.

Comment: How to set the width and height of the chart dynamically according to the data??Image looking so stretched i have tried to give width and height

Comment: You can either put a formula like `Chart1.Width = 25 * points;` where `points` is the number of points on the axis. But I think a better approach would be to limit the number of the points on the axis. Because in this way you can control your image size.

Comment: Could you explain that?I am in need of solution searching from yesterday.

Comment: Just make sure from the code that you display a maximum number of items on your axis (10 for example). This way it will not be stretched.